# Flex CSS resulting in different behavior than flex properties

Tags: angularjs, css, flexbox, angular-material

I'm trying to create a sticky footer with angular material and flexbox. It looks like I have succeeded using `flex-grow: 1 !important;` on my main content element, but it only works as long as I use that code on the element with a `style=""` property. Other options to apply the same rules do not work:

- Applying the CSS in an external file (even with `!important`)
- Applying the CSS in a style element (even with `!important`)
- Using flex properties in the element like `flex="none" flex-grow"1"`

It looks like either angularJS or Angular Material overrides my settings except for the `style=""` property. How can I change this behavior?

I'm suspecting the Angular Material javascript to set my `flex-grow` property to 0, while I want it to be 1, because the property is always at 0 on page load, no matter what I try with CSS and flex properties. Am I right? Is there a good reason for this?

EDIT: I have found multiple examples on how to create a sticky footer, but they all don't work for me. The single solution I have found is the one with a style property mentioned above and I would like a simpler solution.

For example, I cant get this one to work because it would set the flex-grow value to 0.

https://codepen.io/rscafi/pen/bNXRxY/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would use `flex: none` and `flex-grow: 1` in the same declaration.

`flex: none` breaks down to this:

- `flex-grow: 0`
- `flex-shrink: 0`
- `flex-basis: auto`

Then you're overriding the `flex-grow` above with `flex-grow: 1`

You should just consolidate both rules. That would look like this: `flex: 1 0 auto`

Comment: I realized that as soon as I posted the question. I see now that my solution works because it forces `flex-grow: 1;`. It still only works in a style property. EDIT: Nevermind. Your rule in combination with !important seems to work.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that `flex-grow` is part of `flex`, I didn't know that yet. Your solution works in separate CSS without the `!important` tag, and that's all I wanted. It seems flex has some funky interactions when you override rules in the same element, but that's not unacceptable.

Comment: The `flex` property is shorthand for: `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, `flex-basis`.

Comment: My main element looked like this: `<main class="md-padding" layout="row" style="flex:none; flex-grow:1;">`. That worked, and the same ruleset of flex defined in any other location wouldn't work. But your answer is basically the correct way of defining what I was trying to do, and your rule works in every way I need it to.